# Javascript - displaying multiple sql records

Tags: javascript, mysql

```
                for(var i=0; i < data2.length; i++){

                var innerhtml = "<div class='pick'><p id='pick'>"+data2[i].Title+"</p></div>";

                $("#display").append(innerhtml);


                console.log(data2[i]);
            }
```

My web page is only showing back 1 result from my database, how do i change my code to show multiple results?

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing some more code.  What you have here seems quite incomplete.  Also, don't concatenate text right into your HTML.  You're opening yourself to some injection problems, and at a minimum risk creating some ambiguous and invalid HTML.  Set the text property of the element itself.

Comment: If your DB shows 1 result, how can you possibly show multiple results?

Comment: try console.log(data2) and see what is inside?

Comment: Can you show us your `SELECT` statement?  Also when you do get more than one value returned, you're going to end up with multiple `p` elements with the same ID, which is a no-no.

Comment: have added my full for loop

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the value of "innerhtml" every iteration of the loop. Place the declaration for the variable outside the loop (for clarity), then append to it each time; like so

```
var innerhtml = "";

 for(var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++)
     innerHTML += /*your string here*/;
```

Comment: I would assume he's appending it for each iteration of the loop, but you might be right.  Either way, it's impossible to tell without seeing the rest of the loop.

Comment: His example code had a regular "=" inside the loop, I assumed he was taking that string and (outside the loop) placing it into some element's innerHTML property somewhere. Assuming his data is alright, and he has the rest of his code correct, this would cause it to only show one row. But i agree, he ought to do a much better job explaining his question.

Comment: the rest of the loop contains $("#pick").append(innerhtml);